# nginx redirect returning 301 code instead final page

Tags: wordpress, nginx, bitnami

I've created an EC2 instance with Bitnami Wordpress and then I've cloned the instance into a new one.

After that I've modified in both instances this NGINX script to redirect HTTP => HTTPS requests.

```
# HTTP server

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http'){
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}

# HTTPS server

server {
   listen       443 ssl;
   server_name  localhost;

   ssl_certificate      server.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

   ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
   ssl_session_timeout  5m;

   ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

   #include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/phpfastcgi.conf";

   include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf";
}


include "/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-vhosts.conf";
```

Logging via SSH and running `curl -i localhost`, one of the instances works good and return final page source code.

The other instance is returning this:

```
bitnami@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ curl -i localhost
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.14.0
Date: Mon, 04 Feb 2019 16:05:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.22
Location: https://localhost/
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Considering it is a cloned instance, what kind of problem can be happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here:

The X-Forwarded-Proto (XFP) header is a standard header for identifying the protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) that a client used to connect to your proxy or load balancer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto

In this case, as you are connecting directly to the NGINX server, you don't need to use that "if" block, you can simply redirect your request to HTTPS

```
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
```

You can find more information about the https redirection here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/general/apps/wordpress-pro/administration/force-https-nginx/